Why does tailwindcss work in a Vue SFC style block, but not in the template?
I have a Vue single file component to create a custom keyboard. I'm able to use tailwind styles in the style block, but not in the template block. I have tried many elements and tailwind classes; here's a minimal reproduction with one example:
<template>
  /* other keys removed */
  <button @click="keyClicked('Enter')" class="keyboard-key">⏎</button>
</template>

<style scoped>
.keyboard-key {
    @apply border border-gray-300 rounded-md m-0.5;
}
</style>

I want to style the enter key/button. If I add a class (e.g., "bg-red-50") to the button class, there's no effect. If I add the same class to the @apply, all of the keys are pink as expected.
Why does applying a tailwind class in the style block work when applying it to the element itself doesn't? The above tests demonstrate that tailwind is installed and mostly functioning.  I'm mostly using yarn serve, but I have also tried killing and restarting the server, which has no effect.
I'm using:

vue 3.4.21
postcss 8.4.23
tailwindcss 3.4.3

tailwind.config.js has
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx,html}'],
⋮


Consider checking the file the component is in is covered by the content file globs.
